# Galleria 1.3.3 add another gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, galleria

I have an existing galleria html page that has 4 galleries.
[here is the galleria page](https://rickarddesign.com/services/index.html)
I want to add a 5th gallery.
Can't figure out how to link to the image folder to load the images.
Here is the menu.js code:
see the existing 4 galleries - how do I make the flicker set: and the #ID for the new gallery I wnat to add

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //Sidebar Navigation Dropdowns
    $('#no-display-menu.sidebar-menu > li').hoverIntent(primaryNavConfig);

    // check if page has gallery
    if($(".galleria").length > 0) {
        Galleria.loadTheme('../Scripts/galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
        // load fabrication gallery by default
        Galleria.run('.galleria', {
            flickr: 'set:72157638958693776',
            flickrOptions: {
                description: 'true',
                max: 300
            },
            extend: function() {
                var gallery = this;
                gallery.play(4000);
            }
        });
        $(".gallery-title").html("Waterjet Cutting");
    }

    // Change Gallery
    $("#gallery-waterjet").click(function(){
        Galleria.run('.galleria', {
            flickr: 'set:72157638958693776',//Fabrication design
            flickrOptions: {
                description: 'true',
                max: 300
            },
            extend: function() {
                var gallery = this;
                gallery.play(4000);
            }
        });
        $(".gallery-title").html("Waterjet Cutting");

    });

    $("#gallery-fabrication").click(function(){
        Galleria.run('.galleria', {
            flickr: 'set:72157638809874134',//Fabrication design
            flickrOptions: {
                description: 'true',
                max: 300
            },
            extend: function() {
                var gallery = this;
                gallery.play(4000);
            }
        });
        $(".gallery-title").html("Fabrication");

    });
    $("#gallery-3d").click(function(){
        Galleria.run('.galleria', {
            flickr: 'set:72157638807460056',//3d product design
            flickrOptions: {
                description: 'true',
                max: 300
            },
            extend: function() {
                var gallery = this;
                gallery.play(4000);
            }
        });
        $(".gallery-title").html("3D Product Design");

    });
    $("#gallery-contract").click(function(){
        Galleria.run('.galleria', {
            flickr: 'set:72157638808623805',//Contract manufacturing
            flickrOptions: {
                description: 'true',
                max: 300
            },
            extend: function() {
                var gallery = this;
                gallery.play(4000);
            }
        });
        $(".gallery-title").html("Contract Manufacturing");
    });
});

//primaryNav Hover Intent Configuration
var primaryNavConfig = {
    sensitivity: 10,
    interval: 100,
    over: primaryOver,
    out: primaryOut,
    timeout: 250
};

function primaryOver(){$(this).find(">ul").slideDown('fast'); $(this).addClass("hover");}
function primaryOut(){$(this).find(">ul").hide('fast'); $(this).removeClass("hover");}
```

Comment: first create 
        `<div class="gallery-links" id="your_id">
        <img src="your image" alt="">
        <p>title</p>
      </div>`
and then give the id of the div then call in js as `$("#your_id").click(function(){
        Galleria.run('.galleria', {
            flickr: 'set:72157638808623805',//Contract manufacturing
            flickrOptions: {
                description: 'true',
                max: 300
            },
            
        });
        $(".gallery-title").html("Contract Manufacturing");
    });` like above

Comment: Thanks Tamil Selvan - your instructions for Galleria 1.3.3 editing were correct. The biggest trick was in figuring out Flickr's photo sets. Have to be sure and edit each photo to mark as "Public" so flickr can load.